# DJISDKManager Register Failed Without Wi-Fi

Tags: android, dji-sdk

When I use Wi-Fi to register App --> register success,
Use 4G(China Mobile) --> failed or success but need long time.
Do we have to use the Wi-Fi network to register DJI SDKManager?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirements to use Wifi for registration.
This seems to be a bandwidth issue more than anything else since you can have successes after a long time in 4G.

Comment: Thanks. 4G with GPS cost 73 seconds, but without GPS register failed cost 5 seconds.Then I connect to Wifi without GPS register success. Where can I known the registration, location requirement？

Comment: I'm not sure why you have GPS-related issue. It sounds random. Is it 100% reproducible with the situation you mentioned? The reason I ask is because there is no location requirements for registration.

Comment: Yes, 100% when I GPS opened. Strangely, 4 seconds register success without Wifi ignore GPS status. Maybe it is a bandwidth issue. Anyway, thank you for your help.